# Getting You do not currently have a default Web page established for your users. when running VS2008 solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis

I have website in VS2008.  Created the Virtual directory in IIS 5.1.  When I try and run the site to debug from Visual Studio I keep on getting:

> Your Web service is now running.
>
> You do not currently have a default Web page established for your users. Any users attempting to connect to your Web site from another machine are currently receiving an Under Construction page. Your Web server lists the following files as possible default Web pages: default.htm,default.asp,index.htm,iisstart.asp. Currently, only iisstart.asp exists.
>
> To add documents to your default Web site, save files in c:\inetpub\wwwroot.

I have no idea why this is happening.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, it may be as simple as this:

In Solution Explorer, right-click on the page you want to be the default page and click "Set as Start Page".